# BodyParser doesn't parse - but everything looks right to me. How to resolve `Cannot read property of undefined`

Tags: angular, mongodb, express

I cannot for the life of me figured why the post route to `localhost:3000/api/v1/projects/add` doesn't successfully save to the database. All other routes work, but the post route to "/add" returns a 500 internal server error. Saying that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`.

And the console also throw and CORB error:

`Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://localhost:3000/api/v1/projects/add with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.`

The correct object it send from the Angular `admin.service.ts` `saveProject()` method when I `console.log(projectFormData)` but something is clearly wrong on the receiving end since `req.body` cannot be parsed. And it app.js bodyParser seems to be to be loaded in the correct order before the routes.

Can someone spot the mistake.

All help is very much appreciated.

**Express app.**

**app.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var helmet = require("helmet");
var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

// MongoDB connection
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

// Router
var users = require("./routes/users");
var projects = require("./routes/projects");

var app = express();
app.use(helmet());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// CORS
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, PUT, GET, POST");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET");
    return res.status(200).json({});
  }
  next();
});

// Routes
app.use("/api/v1/users", users);
app.use("/api/v1/projects", projects);

module.exports = app;
```

**routes/projects.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var Project = require("../models/project");

var router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  Project.find({})
    .exec()
    .then(result => res.json(result));
});

router.get("/:id", function(req, res, next) {
  Project.findById(req.params.id)
    .exec()
    .then(result => res.json(result));
});

router.post("/add", function(res, req, next) {
  var project = new Project({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description
  });
  project
    .save()
    .then(function(result) {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "Successfully created new project",
        result: result
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Angular client app

**app/admin/add-project/add-project.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Project } from '../../shared/project';
import { AdminService } from '../admin.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-project',
  templateUrl: './add-project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-project.component.css']
})
export class AddProjectComponent {
  projectForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    title: ['', Validators.required],
    description: ['', Validators.required]
  });

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private adminService: AdminService
  ) {}

  onSubmit() {
    this.adminService.saveProject(
      this.projectForm.value.title,
      this.projectForm.value.description
    );
  }
}
```

**app/admin/admin.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Project } from '../shared/project';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminService {
  saveProject(title: string, description: string) {
    const projectFormData: Project = { title, description };
    console.log(projectFormData);
    this.http
      .post<Project>(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/projects/add',
        projectFormData
      )
      .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
}
```

---

postman

```
POST /api/v1/projects/add HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: cc6fd8d2-28c0-4ae7-9392-8602b9c8f401,e814d578-03ce-472d-be70-86f0e7b37373
Host: localhost:3000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 62
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

{
    "title": "postman",
    "description": "this is the postman"
}
```

Response

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, PUT, GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2242
Date: Fri, 16 Aug 2019 11:04:34 GMT
Connection: close
```

Comment: What do you get when you log `req.body`?

Comment: Hi Tien. I see `{ title: "this is my title", description: "save goddamnit" }`

Comment: That's mean `body-parser` has parsed the data

Comment: Sorry. I was looking at the wrong console.log() statement before. If I log `console.log("REQ:BODY", req.body);` I see this logged from the server: `REQ:BODY undefined`.

Comment: Can you use `postman` to test your api?

Comment: Yes sure. I just did. I get the same error. Anything particular you want to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you put your api function's parameters in wrong order.

```
router.post("/add", function(res, req, next) {
```

So you are getting the body from `response` object. Which doesn't have it. The correct order must be

```
router.post("/add", function(req, res, next) {
```

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router

Comment: How could I miss this. THANK YOU